# scripted use of <svg> <defs> <use xlink:href ... via javascript fails

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I try to dynamically create svg path elements in html using JavaScript.
I want to set the paths in a `<defs>` element that later can be reused in `<use>` xlink:href elements.
After creation (press button in the example) the lower part of the screen  remains empty.
The same html, when placed statically works fine. (above the button)
Inspecting in Chrome/Firefox reveals that in the dynamically manipulated dom the #shadow-root (node?) is empty in the dynamically created part whereas it's holding a copy of the path in the static part.

Is there a way to trigger a manual refresh, that I have missed?
Is this generally a forbidden way?
Is there a mistake I made in my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>
        function test() {
            component = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
            component.classList.add("component");
            component.style.left = '0px';
            component.style.top = '0px';
            component.style.width = '800px';
            component.style.height = '400px';
            component.style.position = "absolute";
            document.getElementById("theConnections").appendChild(component);           

            defs = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
            component.appendChild(defs);

            pathdef = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
            pathdef.id = "conn1";
            pathdef.setAttribute("d", "M264 133 L396 132");
            defs.appendChild(pathdef);

            path2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
            path2.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#conn1");
            path2.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
            path2.setAttribute("stroke-width", "9");
            component.appendChild(path2);

            path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
            path.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#conn1");
            path.setAttribute("stroke", "white");
            path.setAttribute("stroke-width", "7");
            component.appendChild(path);

        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .dooferKasten {
            background-color: rgb(82, 69, 50);
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div style="width:800px; height:400px; position: relative" class="dooferKasten">
            <svg class="component" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 400px; position: absolute;">
                <defs><path id="conn0" d="M264 133 L396 132"></path></defs>
                <use xlink:href="#conn0" stroke="black" stroke-width="9"></use>
                <use xlink:href="#conn0" stroke="white" stroke-width="7"></use>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <button onclick="test()">test</button>
        <div style="width:800px; height:400px; position: relative" id="theConnections" class="dooferKasten">
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use setAttribute to set xlink:href as that's in the xlink namespace. You're doing the right thing with namespaces when you createElements with createElementNS, you need to create xlink:href attributes with setAttributeNS

Comment: I changed the code inside test() to:
`pathdef.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "d", "M264 133 L396 132");
path2.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "xlink:href", "#conn1");
path2.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "stroke", "black");
path2.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "stroke-width", "9");
path.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "xlink:href", "#conn1");
path.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "stroke", "white");
path.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "stroke-width", "7"); 
`
But that doen't work either.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Robert Longson. That pointed in the right direction.
I read an article an actually the xlink:href attribute belongs to a different Namespace. So there I had to use 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' instead of 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'.
So following the general advice to always use setAttributeNS inside my svg namespace...

and using null for non prefixed attributes...

and using the correct namespace where that attribute belongs to a whole different namespace, my code looks like that:

```
function test() {
    component = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    component.classList.add("component");
    component.style.left = '0px';
    component.style.top = '0px';
    component.style.width = '800px';
    component.style.height = '400px';
    component.style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("theConnections").appendChild(component);           

    defs = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
    component.appendChild(defs);

    pathdef = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    pathdef.id = "conn1";
    pathdef.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M264 133 L396 132");
    defs.appendChild(pathdef);

    path2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
    path2.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', "xlink:href", "#conn1");
    path2.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "black");
    path2.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "9");
    component.appendChild(path2);

    path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
    path.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', "xlink:href", "#conn1");
    path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "white");
    path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "7");
    component.appendChild(path);

}
```

Comment: If you want you can reduce your JS by moving `stroke` and `stroke-width` in CSS